# How get value from child class

Tags: c#

How to get value from the children to the parent class. 
I want to sum the `price` of flowers and bring it as the sum(`coast`) of the whole bouquet

```
abstract class Bouquet
{
    public List<Flower> _flowers = new List<Flower>();
    public List<Flower> Flowers
    {
        get { return _flowers; }
        private set { _flowers = value; }
    }
    public decimal Coast { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public Bouquet(int c)
    {
        this.Count = c;
        for (int i=0;i< Count; i++){//
          Coast = Flowers.Sum(flower => flower.price);
        }
        this.CreateBouquet();
    }




    //Factory method
    public abstract void CreateBouquet();
}

class RosesStandard:Bouquet
{
    public RosesStandard(int c) : base(c)
    {

    }
    public override void CreateBouquet()
    {
        Flowers.Add(new Rose());
    }


}`
```

And `Flower` looks like:

```
    public class Flower
{
    public decimal price { get; set; }

}

///<summary>
/// concrete flower
/// </summary>
class Rose:Flower
{
    public Rose()
    {
        price = 100;
    }
}`
```

ps sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Be more precise with your question. Which value are you targeting and what do you want to do with it?

Comment: Also, do you want to calculate the cost after you've created the bouquet?  Right now, you are calculating the cost `c` times and then adding flowers to the bouquet.  Put brackets around the statements you want repeated in your for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things wrong with your code. Primarily though I think you're over complicating the situation. See below on the abstract that might simplify it for you:
_flowers should be private not public.
Your constructor for Bouquet takes in a count where you try to calculate the cost but it'll obviously be 0 since the are no flowers yet.
this.CreateBouquet should be removed but I'm not sure I understand why it's there. But I'm confident that it won't do what you expect it to. See below to see if that helps you get a little further.

```
abstract class Bouquet
    {
        private List<Flower> _flowers = new List<Flower>();
        public List<Flower> Flowers
        {
            get { return _flowers; }
            private set { _flowers = value; }
        }
        public decimal Cost { get { return _flowers.Sum(p => p.Price); } }
        public int Count { get { return _flowers.Count(); } }
        public Bouquet()
        {


        }




        //Factory method
        public abstract void CreateBouquet();
    }
```

Comment: Well, yep sure, _flower should be private. Simply, i don't know how sum up all flower in bouquete, with your example perhaps, i'll better, to be honnest,   i brake my brain with it). maybe full code write?

Comment: @Fel Your question asked how to get the cost. I showed you how to the the cost. I don't think it's appropriate to ask to get your project and fix it for you.

Comment: And I did not want to Fix my project, I just do not quite understand the logic, but maybe I need to sleep)

Comment: Sleep, and I think I understand, I tried to summarize what does not exist. Thank you)